# Accessing a proxied contracts address and code

Tags: web3js

I am trying to read a proxied contract and I want to find out where the proxy points to.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48#readProxyContract
This is the USDC proxied contract.

This lets me successfully read the proxied contract

```
new web3.eth.Contract(ERC20_ABI, contractAddress).methods.symbol().call();
```

This lets me NOT read the address of the implementation:

```
new web3.eth.Contract(PROXY_ABI, contractAddress).methods.implementation().call()
```

And I guess that the reason is that the call is delegated to the proxied contract and there the
method implementation() is not available.